# Sharing Laravel Session Across Subdomains CSRF TOKEN MISMATCH

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

First of all i already did a lot of research on this topic as i didn't want to waste anyone's time but i didn't found concrete answers.

I need to share a laravel session across SubDomains so that when the user logs out of one SubDomains, he logs out of all SubDomains.
I currently have two SubDomains (/login_master and /light), and both the session files are configured to use database driver.
This is what they look like:

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 30,

'expire_on_close' => false,


 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

Im not sure if the domain is setup correctly (right now it looks like this ".192.168.1.249") and they both have the same cookie name.
When i try to login i get token mismatch somehow even tough i have included the CSRF_FIELD in the form that makes the request.

Can anyone shed some light into this issue please?

Thank You